# basil.js scripts taking minutes to run

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign, basil.js

I'm trying to create an InDesign script using basil.js but the scripts take minutes before running. InDesign just freezes in the meanwhile. Other JS samples (not using basil) work fine. I'm using InDesign 2021 and the MacOS Big Sur 11.2. Could that be it? I'm afraid, for me, the solution cannot be downgrading. Any other thoughts?

Thanks a lot, Daniel

```
#includepath
"Users/danifslopes/Documents";
#include
"basiljs/bundle/basil.js";

function draw() {
    b.doc(); //with or without, the same result (I have a page opened)
    b.text("hello", 100, 100, 200, 200);
}

b.go();
```

Comment: Have you tried running the script again and see, if it still takes that long? If you run scripts in the ESTK for the first time, it might take a few minutes, because it needs to load some dictionaries initially. However, on any subsequent runs it should run quick.

Also (but this is unrelated to your issue), you might want to look into using the new (but still unreleased) version of basil. This has been in development forever and is still unreleased, but I have successfully used it in my teaching for a while. Here's some instructions how to install it: https://github.com/trych/MuTypo

Comment: Having said all that, I have not used basil.js under InDesign 2021 and MacOS Big Sur 11.2, so if it turns out that gives you still issues, that would be interesting for the basil.js dev team to know and you should open an issue in their Github Issue tracker: https://github.com/basiljs/basil.js/issues

Comment: Hi @daniel Yes this is wired. Since ESTK is depreacted we suggest using Sublime Text or VSCode to run Extendscripts. WE also have already a v2 of Basil ready (since you are using the old syntax I guess you got your instructions from the basiljs.ch website). 
Maybe you head over to or discourse https://basiljs.discourse.group/ and try to get some help there or you write us an issue on github as mdomino suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed the instructions in [github.com/trych/MuTypo](http://github.com/trych/MuTypo) to use the new version of basil and it seems to work great. Also, this version seems to be much simpler and practical to use.

Thanks a lot, mdomino and fabianmoronzirfas.